# Get Image/Transform/Shape to rotate to Follow Mouse Cursor in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, cursor, mouse

I have tried to do this, but at certain positions, the object, in this case, my `ImageView`, will just "teleport" to another degree.

How can I make it not be choppy and properly follow my mouse cursor in a JavaFX scene?

Comment: Can you please the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently in a blog post about [how to create a heat seeking missile](http://wecode4fun.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/heat-seeking-missiles-heat-seeking.html).

The relevant part for you is this code fragment:

```
public void move() {  

 SpriteBase follower = this;  

 if( target != null)  
 {  
  //get distance between follower and target  
  double distanceX = target.getCenterX() - follower.getCenterX();  
  double distanceY = target.getCenterY() - follower.getCenterY();  

  //get total distance as one number  
  double distanceTotal = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);  

  //calculate how much to move  
  double moveDistanceX = this.turnRate * distanceX / distanceTotal;  
  double moveDistanceY = this.turnRate * distanceY / distanceTotal;  

  //increase current speed  
  follower.dx += moveDistanceX;  
  follower.dy += moveDistanceY;  

  //get total move distance  
  double totalmove = Math.sqrt(follower.dx * follower.dx + follower.dy * follower.dy);  

  //apply easing  
  follower.dx = missileSpeed * follower.dx/totalmove;  
  follower.dy = missileSpeed * follower.dy/totalmove;  

 }   

 //move follower  
 follower.x += follower.dx;  
 follower.y += follower.dy;  

 //rotate follower toward target  
 double angle = Math.atan2(follower.dy, follower.dx);  
 double degrees = Math.toDegrees(angle) + 90;  

 follower.r = degrees;  

}
```

The follower is your object and the target is the mouse cursor. You could use the Java 8 features of Point2D to calculate the distance, that would make the code even less. I didn't do it for compatibility reasons to Java 7.

Let me know if this helps you. If it isn't what you're looking for, please be more precise.